# How to make a multicore system using the RISC-V Rocket-chip processor

Tags: multicore, riscv

I want to make a multicore using zedboard. I have a 2 question about that.

1. I changed a variable 'NTILES' to 2 in rocket-chip/src/main/scala/Configs.scala for implementing multicore system.
2. If I make a multicore, how do I confirm that? I tried using fork and background execution to check the modified system, but I received error message like below picture. And pthreads couldn't be compiled. I want to know the method to confirm the multicore system.

Also if you have any idea about making multicore for rocketchip, please notify me the knowhow. thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged `pthreads`? Are you using an operating system?

Comment: You need to further explain how you compiled your software to run on your multi-core rocket-chip processor. There is too little information for us to go on.

Answer (score 3):

With NTILES=2 and the DefaultFPGAConfig, two cores may not fit on a zedboard. I would verify Vivado was able to complete successfully. You will probably need to decrease some of the other parameters (BTB, FPU, etc.).

The proxy kernel (riscv-pk) does not support multicore. To use linux, you will need to enable SMP support when building it. When doing menuconfig for linux, under "Platform Type" turn on "Symmetric Multi-Processing." For pthreads, I would copy the correct shared library from riscv-gcc-linux's compiler directory to your linux disk image.

Once you have SMP linux booting on the board, you can confirm it is multicore with `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. For testing your software (linux, disk image, your code), I would recommend using [spike](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim) and moving to the FPGA when you are confident the parallel software is ready. Spike can simulate multicore.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. You said I need to enable SMP support to use linux. That 'linux' means petalinux in the zedboard??? I want to make sure what that meaning because I'm little bit confused about meaning of 'linux'.

Comment: By linux I mean [riscv-linux](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-linux). As for the distribution (disk image), I would stick with a basic busybox one for now. The [riscv-poky](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-poky) distribution generator is great, but it needs to be updated for the new privileged ISA. I would look at the [README](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools) within riscv-tools for instructions on building and using linux on RISC-V.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've tried using linux on the zedboard and execute the test file which is compiled by  riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc. However, There is a problem to do this. we tried './test' but It doesn't work. And we found the 'ash' and tried to use that but It doesn't work also. we typed 'ash test' and the message on the terminal was 'test: line 10: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting ")")'. this test file is just the object file which print 'hello world' and It works on the ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please give me an advice for executing the object file on the zedboard using linux? Should I use the ash? or Is there any other way to execute the file? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would use the ash shell included within busybox. For more instructions on how to use riscv-linux on the zedboard, I would check the FPGA repo's README (https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq#booting). To execute your file, you are going to need to add it to the disk image (boot.bin). Sometimes the error messages from ash (in busybox) are misleading, so I would check the file is visible, executable, etc...

Comment: Thank you. We tried many things. First, we changed Ntiles=2 in DefaultFPGAConfig. Second, we did menuconfig for linux and turn on "SMP" under "Platform Type". And for testing, we put the test code into the 'bin' directory and excute this by typing 'time ./a & ./a'. In here, '&' means that we did background executing for checking if the system executes in multicore system. Finally, we checked the 'cpuinfo' in the proc directory but nothing is changed. Just we can see ' hart : 0, isa: RV64G'. Anythings we should change more? I think 'cpuinfo' should be changed but it didn't. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure you can fit two DefaultFPGAConfig cores onto the zedboard's FPGA? For us it fails to complete because it cannot fit, and we have to make the core smaller by reducing BTB entries or removing the FPU. From within the fpga-zynq/zedboard did you run make rocket to generate new verilog?