# Linux doesn't recognize multicore Rocket on FPGA

Tags: linux, riscv

I follow the instructions at [How to make a multicore system using the RISC-V Rocket-chip processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517472/how-to-make-a-multicore-system-using-the-risc-v-rocket-chip-processor) to generate a multicore Rocket for FPGA (board: Xilinx ZC706), but the Linux doesn't recognize the additional core.

I am sure that the Linux is well with SMP, because when I replacing FPGA with either rocket-chip emulator or Spike ISA simulator, it recognizes multicores.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWMv4.png)

Update: after applying the multicore fix commit, the riscv Linux halts:

```
root@zynq:~# ./fesvr-zynq +disk=/nfs/root.bin bbl /nfs/linux-3.14.33/vmlinux 
              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrr       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  
rrrrrrrrrrrrr       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
rr                vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
rr            vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rr
rrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrr
rrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrr
rrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vv      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr          rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

       INSTRUCTION SETS WANT TO BE FREE

****************Sometimes halt here************************

[    0.000000] Linux version 3.14.33-g043bb5d (guanglin@guanglin-a11-linux) (gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) ) #5 SMP Tue Oct 13 14:56:14 EDT 2015
[    0.000000] Detected 0xfe00000 bytes of physical memory
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @ffffffff8062d000 s9432 r0 d23336 u32768
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 64135
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/htifblk0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] Memory: 253320K/260096K available (1898K kernel code, 119K rwdata, 368K rodata, 85K init, 221K bss, 6776K reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:2
[    0.150000] Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 20.02 BogoMIPS (lpj=100145)
[    0.150000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.150000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.150000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.150000] Brought up 2 CPUs
[    0.150000] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.150000] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.150000] Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.150000] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
[    0.150000] TCP: reno registered
[    0.150000] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.150000] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.150000] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.150000] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.150000] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.180000] htifcon htif1: detected console
[    0.190000] console [htifcon0] enabled
[    0.190000] htifblk htif2: detected disk
[    0.190000] htifblk htif2: added htifblk0
[    0.190000] TCP: cubic registered

****************Sometimes halt here************************

[    0.190000] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 254:0.
[    0.190000] devtmpfs: mounted
[    0.190000] Freeing unused kernel memory: 84K (ffffffff80000000 - ffffffff80015000)
/ # 
/ # 
/ # cd /
/ # cd /usr
/usr # echo abc
abc
/usr # ls

****************Sometimes halt here************************
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially *links* to images of texts. First of all not everybody can read text in images, secondly links may go away possibly making your question totally worthless. Instead *copy and paste* the actual text into the question body.

Comment: good idea, thanks. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: SMP linux sometimes halting after running ls is a bug (will happen under spike too). It would be great if you could debug it.

Comment: Surprisingly, I didn't observe the fragility of SMP Linux on Spike. Now I see Spike SMP Linux stalls at some time, but less frequently than FPGA. @user2548418

Answer (score 2):

You will need to rebuild riscv-fesvr and install that onto the FPGA. This [commit](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-fesvr/commit/5fc6b74b2b1fb3232093f9e7299f23e042bc81c3) fixed that. Instructions for [rebuilding riscv-fesvr](https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq#fesvr).

Comment: Thank you so much! After rebuilding, the riscv linux recognizes the second core at boot time. However, the riscv linux then stalls sooner on later (sometimes I couldn't even see the kernel booting information from the screen). The boot command I am using is "LD_PRELOAD=./libfesvr.so ./fesvr-zedboard +disk=/path/to/root.bin bbl /path/to/vmlinux "

Comment: Following instructions for [rebuilding riscv-fesvr](https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq#fesvr) generates fesvr-zedboard, but I am using a bigger ZC706 actually. Does it matter?

Comment: No, you can rename it fesvr-zynq. You can copy libfesvr.so to /usr/local/lib on the board.

Comment: Thank you. But I doubt the maturity of that multicore fix [commit](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-fesvr/commit/5fc6b74b2b1fb3232093f9e7299f23e042bc81c3). The RISCV Linux halts very soon after boot. However, if I rollback to a previous git commit without that fix, the RISCV Linux work very well with one core.

Comment: I updated my question so you can see where RISCV Linux halts. thanks.